# Oracle Need multirow data in a single column

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql, oracle11g

I have table like this

```
 COLA    COLB
  A       1
  A       2
  A       3
  B       12
  B       6
  C       8
```

I want output like below

```
 COLA      COLB
   A        1|2|3
   B        12|6
   C        8
```

Please help me!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this. This works for Oracle 9i above.

```
select 
   COLA,
   rtrim (xmlagg (xmlelement (e, COLB || ' | ')).extract ('//text()'), ' | ') COLB
from 
   [table_name]
group by 
   COLA
;
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `listagg()`:

```
select cola, listagg(colB, '|') within group (order by NULL)
from table t
group by cola;
```

The `order by NULL` specifies no *particular* order, but it doesn't guarantee ordering.  You should have an explicit column for that, if the order makes a difference.

EDIT:

In earlier versions of Oracle, you can use `wm_concat()`:

```
select cola, replace(wmsys.wm_concat(colB), ',', '|')
from table t
group by cola;
```

Comment: I cant use LISTAGG as ma Server version is 11.1 unfortunately